# How to specify data type for RactiveForm in Angular 4+?

Tags: forms, angular

For a field that should be number, currently it returns string. I am not sure it is a feature that is not implemented yet or just I don't know how to configure it correctly.

```
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        number: new FormControl()
    });

    console.log(this.form.value);
```

I need it to be number natively when I call `this.form.value`. There is a tree structure in form. It will be the very last options for me to cast them one by one.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In the Input field, use this pattern to make sure the user can only enter digits: `pattern="[0-9]*"`

then you can use `Number(<your bind variable>)` to get it as a number.

Comment: did you put  `type="number" ` in the html template for the corresponding input?

Comment: can you pleaase provide a plunker with the exact scenario?